# Recommendation system for Time-Series data

Tags: python, machine-learning, recommendation-engine, knn

I have a problem where I need to recommend optimal values for certain parameters to drive an industrial process with objective to increase production.

#### Data:

I have 1 year's **Time-Series** data having continuous values. Data is recorded at a **5 mins** time interval. Total features = **6** (all continuous). Data **dimensions** = (70000, 6). **NOTE:** It's time-series so the index is **time_stamp**.

#### Goal:

(Pardon if I am using incorrect terminology) I want to train a model where I can recommend optimal values for **4 out of 6** variables based on the remaining **2** variables.

#### So far:

Based on basic research, I have developed following points:

1. Framed the problem as a supervised learning problem, by constructing the data with *t-1* as **X** and *t* as **y**. 
   **NOTE:** *t* represents data at current time_stamp and *t-1* for previous time_stamp. (Followed [article](https://machinelearningmastery.com/convert-time-series-supervised-learning-problem-python/))

**1.1.** Trained as LSTM (described [here](https://machinelearningmastery.com/multivariate-time-series-forecasting-lstms-keras/)). Didn't performed well. Didn't try much network tweaking. I believe the way I am treating the problem is what needs revision.

2. Treated the problem as a recommendation system on numerical data. Did following:

**2.1.** K-NN variation - recommended values of dependent variables **4 out of 6** by finding the records in the data that are closes to the values independent variables  **2 variables**.

```
data = ...
to_pred = [D1, D2, D3, D4, I1, I2]
# D1...D4 -> Dependent Variables (to recommend)
# I1, I2  -> Independent Variables

GetClosest(data, example):
    closest = match data[I1, I2] with [I1, I2] values of all records
    return closest[D1, D2, D3, D4]

to_pred[D1, D2, D3, D4] = GetClosest(data, to_pred[I1, I2])
```

This works fine. As it should. No learning involved. Simple Calculation.

Problem with this is inherited from k-NN. Data requires to be loaded into the memory, which is not a good practice, esp. if the data is too much (I believe).

#### Questions:

1. Which of the above formulation of the problem seems reasonable. Or none of them does?
2. In forecasting I can implement it any way ARIMA or LSTM. But how can I formulate the problem so the network gets trained and is accurate.
3. In treating the problem as k-NN.

   3.1. Is it right to do this? Is this considered recommendation (in ML perspective)?

   3.2. Any way to overcome the memory issue? Maybe, there is some variation or advanced form of k-NN?

Again, please pardon any mistakes (BUT, please point out). Still learning.

Comment: What's your goal?  Am I understanding correctly that, ultimately, you'd like a system which will tweak those four input parameters in order to control for specific output values?

Comment: That is the goal. Recommending 4 variables based on remaining 2 variables.

Comment: @RagingRoosevelt. Please find above the description to your question.